# Creating curvy symbol for letter 'l'

Tags: symbols

I am using a formula where I have to use $\boldsumbol l$. However on the slide, it looks like the letter capital I. How can I have a nice curvy version to denote vector l?

Comment: Not a duplicate. I checked those sites and they did not give me a concrete answer. Bernard has done the job for me.

Comment: Other options you have: 1. In the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, load a math font that comes with a bold version (XITS, Libertinus or Minion). 2: In `unicode-math`, load a bold math font with `\setmathfont[version=bold]`. 3: In the legacy toolchain, load the `bm` package after amsmath/mathtools.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Like that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

  $ \ell ~ \boldsymbol\ell $

\end{document}
```

[image: Normal curly l and a bold curly l]